# Django pagination dependent on ordering

Tags: django, pagination

I have the following model (simplified):

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-date_created',) # note the "reverse" ordering here
```

, then my custom DetailView based on `generic.DetailView`:

```
class PostDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
```

and, finally, the following template:

```
{% with object.get_previous_by_date_created as prev %}
    {% if prev %}
    <a class="nav-link-prev"
       href="{% url "blog:post_detail" pk=prev.id %}">Previous</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endwith %}

{% with object.get_next_by_date_created as next %}
    {% if next %}
    <a class="nav-link-next"
       href="{% url "blog:post_detail" pk=next.id %}">Next</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

My pagination implemented this way works, but due to the reverse ordering (i.e `-date_created`) field, its Previous/Next labels are misplaced. In other words my template outputs "Previous" where it should be "Next", and vice versa. If I remove a `-` sign in `ordering = ('-date_created',)` it will work fine, but that's not the ordering I would like to have on my website.

Is there an easy and idiomatic way of fixing this misbehavior? What am I missing?

Comment: So only the labels are changed (Next | Previous), otherwise it works fine?

Comment: @HoratiuJeflea all link HTMLs.

Comment: Can you please add `order_by` in your `queryset` like `queryset = Post.objects.all().order_by('-date_created')` and check your output.

Comment: @MKPatel Tried your approach. I don't see anything changed.

Comment: as a hack I might use `{% with object.get_next_by_date_created as prev %}` and `{% with object.get_previous_by_date_created as next %}` but it is ugly.

Comment: Might be it is not good as before you wrote your template.

Comment: @MKPatel I am unsure I understand what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went this route and was able to solve the issue:

```
class PostDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        next = Post.objects.filter(pk__lt=self.object.pk).order_by('-pk')[:1]
        prev = Post.objects.filter(pk__gt=self.object.pk).order_by('pk')[:1]
        if prev:
            context['prev'] = prev[0]
        if next:
            context['next'] = next[0]

        return context
```

now in template.html:

```
{% if prev %}
<a class="nav-link-prev"
   href="{% url "post_detail" pk=prev.id %}">Previous
</a>
{% endif %}

{% if next %}
    <a class="nav-link-next"
       href="{% url "post_detail" pk=next.id %}">Next
    </a>
{% endif %}
```

What do you think of this approach?

Comment: Yes, logically you are write but if Django is provides inbuilt functionality to use prev/next then why we should write our logic to apply same functionality. :)

Comment: No, logically they are not the same. I am yet to see the "inbuilt" functionality, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
ordering = ['-date_created']
```

or

```
ordering = Post._meta.ordering
```

to `PostListView`

Comment: My question is related to `generic.DetailView`, not `generic.ListView`, I updated it. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to use `DetailView` with `mixin`  `MultipleObjectMixin` like below...

```
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from django.views.generic.list import MultipleObjectMixin
from django.core import paginator

class PostDetailView(DetailView, MultipleObjectMixin):
    model = Post
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        object_list = Post.objects.all().order_by('-date_created')
        context = super(PostDetailView, self).get_context_data(object_list=object_list, **kwargs)
        post_paginator = paginator.Paginator(object_list, self.paginate_by)
        # Catch invalid page numbers
        try:
            post_page_obj = post_paginator.page(purchases_page)
        except (paginator.PageNotAnInteger, paginator.EmptyPage):
            post_page_obj = post_paginator.page(1)

        context["post_page_obj"] = post_page_obj
        return context
```

Now, you should be able to use pagination method with `post_page_obj` variable

Comment: Thank you, it did the trick. By the way, it works also without `paginate_by = 5` in your code snippet. Could you explain why?

Comment: Yes because if don't write `paginate_by` it will take default pagination.

Comment: I am still not sure it works with "default" template code I posted in my question.

Comment: But the template code before you edited is easy to understand and easy to use.

Comment: reference of `paginate_by` in Django doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.paginate_by

Comment: with your code snippet I have prev/next links being disappeared.

Comment: Ok let me check

Comment: You can refer more from this Django doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/pagination/#paginating-a-listview

Comment: What is `purchases_page`? How is it relevant to my model? And why is it `paginate_by = 5`? Have you checked your code?